# Track all Android Input Events

Tags: android, user-interaction, user-tracking

Do you know any Option to track all Input-Events of an application?

I want to keep all input events of one "instance" of using an application for automated testing. For instance those:
- Click on EditText1
- Type in the Text "abc"
- Click on button "Ok"
- New Activity starts
- Click xy

This should happen without rewriting the whole code of the app.

I currently don't know where to start :/

**Edit:** I want to go into the direction of Testdroid or Monkeytalk.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use Logging using on events like`onclick()` events, `TextWatcher` methods, `onTouch()` events, etc. But you cannot upload this project for GooglePlay because in the process of uploading and signing the app, it asks for removing all the Logging statements from our Application Project.

Comment: Does that mean I need to add a line like Log.i(..,...) to each listener? That's kind of rewriting lots of classes, what I want to avoid if possible

Comment: Hi, can you please post a link to the exact destination where Google asks for removing Logging statements?

Comment: @user2331454 is this what you needed ? http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/preparing.html  --or--  http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/publishing_overview.html